# Динамическая верхнетреугольная матрица

Tags: c++, указатели, матрицы

Нужно задать верхнюю треугольную матрицу размера `3х3`. Размер строк задаётся динамически.

```
int *matrix[3] = {new int[3],new int[2],new int};
```

В таком случае получится нечто следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как так сделать? Пробовал создавать все строки размером `3` и потом удалять первые ненужные элементы оператором `delete`, но компилятор ругается.

Comment: Укажите язык программирования в метках, исправив вопрос.

Comment: `int *matrix[3] = { new int[3], new int[2] - sizeof(int), new int - 2 * sizeof(int) };`

Comment: это принцип, не помню точно, как смещать указатели. Возможно, просто `- 1` и `- 2`.

Comment: Попробуйте `std::vector`

Comment: @user176262 и у вас всё обвалится. Правильно так: `int *matrix[3] = { new int[3], new int[2] - 1, new int[1] - 2 };`. Арифметика указателей - наше всё! И обращу внимание на `new int[1]` вместо `new int` - это исключит потенциальное UB.

Comment: Вычисление адресов до начала массива тоже неопределённое поведение. `new int[1] - 2` - так не надо делать.

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы написали, это абсолютно правильный способ задания верхней треугольной матрицы, в то же время, вопрос только в том, как вы будете её для себя интерпретировать, а также то, как обходить. В памяти это выглядит следующим образом: есть 3 стоящих рядом элемента по 4 или 8 байт (в зависимости от разрядности приложения), а каждый из них ссылается на 3 разных куска оперативной памяти.

Удалять элементы по отдельности из динамического массива нельзя, только весь массив целиком.

Вот вам пример того, как я интерпретирую эту матрицу как верхнетреугольную.

```
int *matrix[3] = {new int[3], new int[2], new int};

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = i; j < 3; ++j)
    {
      matrix[i][j - i] = 1;
    }
  }


  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    for(int k = 0; k < i; ++k) cout << "\t";
    for(int j = 0; j < 3 - i; ++j)
      cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
  }
```

Comment: `new int` -> `new int[1]`. Можно было бы оставить так, но тогда при удалении придётся по разному удалять последний элемент и все остальные.

Answer (score 0):

Или вот ещё такой вариант, через специальный класс. Хотя вряд ли ваш препод такое примет. Однако ознакомиться, думаю, всё равно будет полезно. Это к вопросу об интерпретации данных.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdexcept>


class CUpTriangleMatrix
{
    size_t  m_size;
    int*    m_pValues;

public:
    CUpTriangleMatrix(size_t size, ...)
    {
        m_size = size;

        size_t numValues = size*(size+1)/2;
        m_pValues = new int[numValues];

        va_list values;
        va_start(values, size);

        for (size_t i=0; i<numValues; ++i)
            m_pValues[i] = va_arg(values, int);

        va_end(values);
    }

    inline ~CUpTriangleMatrix() {delete[] m_pValues;}

    int& operator()(size_t row, size_t col)
    {
        if ((row < m_size) && (col >= row) && (col < m_size))
            return m_pValues[row*m_size + col - row*(row+1)/2];
        throw std::out_of_range("indecies are out of matrix range!");
    }
};


int main()
{
    CUpTriangleMatrix m(3, 1,2,3, 4,5, 6);

    printf(
        "%d\t" "%d\t" "%d\n"
        "\t"   "%d\t" "%d\n"
        "\t"   "\t"   "%d\n",

        m(0,0), m(0,1), m(0,2),
                m(1,1), m(1,2),
                        m(2,2)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Будет выведено:

```
1       2       3
        4       5
                6
```

Answer (score 0):

Видя эту задачу невозможно не хулиганить.

Верхнетреугольная матрица размера *n* содержит *(n + 1)n/2* элементов (формула суммы арифметической прогрессии). Будем хранить их в одном массиве друг за другом. Первые *i* строк в таком массиве займут *n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + (n - (i - 1)) = (n + (n - (i - 1)))i/2* позиций (опять формула суммы арифметической прогрессии).

Оператор `[]` возвращает указатель на начало *i*-той строки. Но от начала отнимается *i*, так что строка правильно адресуется - не от нуля, а от *i*. После упрощения формула для начала строки такая: *(2n - i - 1)i/2*.

Карта памяти для *n = 5*:

> ```
> data -> [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
> m[0] -> [ 0  1  2  3  4]
> m[1] -------------> [ ?  5  6  7  8]
> m[2] ----------------------> [ ?  ?  9 10 11]
> m[3] ----------------------------> [ ?  ?  ? 12 13]
> m[4] -------------------------------> [ ?  ?  ?  ? 14]
> ```

Код демонстрирует адреса элементов матрицы:

```
#include <iostream>

class UTMatrix {
public:
    UTMatrix(int n) : n(n), data(new int[(n + 1) * n / 2]) {}
    UTMatrix(const UTMatrix &m) = delete;
    ~UTMatrix() { delete [] data; }
    UTMatrix &operator =(const UTMatrix &m) = delete;

    int *operator[](int i) { return data + ((2 * n - i - 1) * i / 2); }

private:
    int n;
    int *data;
};

int main() {
    const int n = 4;
    UTMatrix m(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            std::cout << "? ";
        }
        for (int j = i; j < n; ++j) {
            std::cout << &m[i][j] - &m[0][0] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ utmatrix.cpp
>
> $ ./a.out
> 0 1 2 3 
> ? 4 5 6 
> ? ? 7 8 
> ? ? ? 9
> ```